# windows refuses to boot from original nvme drive after cloning to a sata drive

Tags: boot, multi-boot, windows-11, clone

Background:

After learning about a potential firmware issue with one of my nvme drives (search: Samsung 980/990 pro read-only bricking 2023 February). I decided to apply the appropriate firmware updates to the Samsung drive. The easiest way to do so is from Windows using the Samsung magician software.

Before doing any of that I decided to clone the win11 system to a SATA drive and the same with my Linux system. In a nutshell the cloning process could be described like this:

```
 nvme1 (force mp600) -> sata1  { Windows 11 }
 nvme2 (evo 980 pro) -> sata2  { Linux }
```

All of the drives in question have the same 2tb capacity. I used dd_rescue to clone the original drives to the sata drives. There were no I/O errors during that process.

The original linux (980 pro) and clone are doing fine, and despite having found an alarming amount of SMART errors on the 980 nvme, it seems do be doing fine. The firmware patch is applied and that's over and dealt with.

The problem:

After booting the "isolated windows system" from the mp600 nvme as usual, with the intention to download samsung magician and apply the patch to the other 980-nvme drive, the following happened:

Windows decided to use the cloned partition for the C: drive from the cloned drive. Presumably because the SATA drives are discovered before the NVME drives in this BIOS and on this motherboard (x570 pro4 by asrock). So after a painfully slow boot process and a lot of cursing I realized that Windows is now using C: from the much slower *cloned* drive instead of using the original.

To this I thought, well no big deal. I'll just unplug the clone and boot as usual. Nope.

BSOD.

```
Recovery
Your PC/Device needs to be repaired
A required device isn't connected or can't be accessed

Error code: 0xc000000e {0x c000 000e}

You'll need to use recovery tools (bla, bla, bla)
```

I tried to apply the "usual" repair-from installation media fix. Nope:

BSOD.

```
 Startup Repair couldn't repair your PC.
 Press "advanced options" to try other options to repair your PC or "Shut down" to turn off your PC.

 Log file: \System32\Logfiles\Srt\SrtTrail.txt
```

Since then, I've tried to clone back from the SATA clone to the NVME, with the same last BSOD as the final result.

Curiously enough the original system boots just fine from the cloned drive and the C, D, E partitions from the source are replaced too, while the original partitions are assigned to "later" letters such as h,e,f.

I've also tried to manually apply the C letter(`*`) to the original drive, and after that doing the repair-your-system step from the installation USB. However, the OS or the BIOS seem to prefer the SATS drive, and if the SATA drive is not connected I get the first BSOD.

To summarize:

When booting with original and clone present, clone is selected.
When booting without clone, Windows reports a missing device and stops with a BSOD.

Presumably, migrating to a new drive is a common use case, so that's probably what happened. However, I want to boot from the original nvme and not from the sata clone. Do you have any experience with this issue? I could use some suggestions.

---

log output:

```
  Startup Repair diagnosis and repair log
  ---------------------------
  Last successful boot time: ‎2/‎14/‎2023 2:16:36 PM (GMT)
  Number of repair attempts: 1
  
  Session details
  ---------------------------
  System Disk = \Device\Harddisk2
  Windows directory = D:\Windows
  AutoChk Run = 0
  Number of root causes = 1
  
  Test Performed: 
  ---------------------------
  Name: Check for updates
  Result: Completed successfully. Error code =  0x0
  Time taken = 0 ms
  
  Test Performed: 
  ---------------------------
  Name: System disk test
  Result: Completed successfully. Error code =  0x0
  Time taken = 0 ms
  
  Test Performed: 
  ---------------------------
  Name: Disk failure diagnosis
  Result: Completed successfully. Error code =  0x0
  Time taken = 93 ms
  
  Test Performed: 
  ---------------------------
  Name: Disk metadata test
  Result: Completed successfully. Error code =  0x0
  Time taken = 407 ms
  
  Test Performed: 
  ---------------------------
  Name: Disk metadata test
  Result: Completed successfully. Error code =  0x0
  Time taken = 78 ms
  
  Test Performed: 
  ---------------------------
  Name: Target OS test
  Result: Completed successfully. Error code =  0x0
  Time taken = 15 ms
  
  Test Performed: 
  ---------------------------
  Name: Volume content check
  Result: Completed successfully. Error code =  0x0
  Time taken = 1735 ms
  
  Test Performed: 
  ---------------------------
  Name: Boot manager diagnosis
  Result: Completed successfully. Error code =  0x0
  Time taken = 0 ms
  
  Test Performed: 
  ---------------------------
  Name: System boot log diagnosis
  Result: Completed successfully. Error code =  0x0
  Time taken = 15 ms
  
  Test Performed: 
  ---------------------------
  Name: Event log diagnosis
  Result: Completed successfully. Error code =  0x0
  Time taken = 125 ms
  
  Test Performed: 
  ---------------------------
  Name: Internal state check
  Result: Completed successfully. Error code =  0x0
  Time taken = 0 ms
  
  Test Performed: 
  ---------------------------
  Name: Check for installed LCU
  Result: Completed successfully. Error code =  0x0
  Time taken = 20250 ms
  
  Test Performed: 
  ---------------------------
  Name: Check for installed driver updates
  Result: Completed successfully. Error code =  0x0
  Time taken = 735 ms
  
  Test Performed: 
  ---------------------------
  Name: Check for pending package install
  Result: Completed successfully. Error code =  0x0
  Time taken = 1828 ms
  
  Test Performed: 
  ---------------------------
  Name: Boot status test
  Result: Completed successfully. Error code =  0x0
  Time taken = 16 ms
  
  Root cause found: 
  ---------------------------
  Boot status indicates that the OS booted successfully.
  
  ---------------------------
  ---------------------------
```

---

`*` applying c letter to original drive

USB boot media -> advanced tools
-> cmd prompt
-> diskpart
-> select disk 3
-> select volume 4
-> assign letter=c

---

#### Partitions on both drives

```
PS C:\Users\jaro> Get-PhysicalDisk  | Where-Object -Property FriendlyName -Match "(Force|ST2000)" | Select-Object -Property MediaType,Model,Size

MediaType Model                       Size
--------- -----                       ----
SSD       Force MP600        2000398934016
HDD       ST2000DX001-1CM164 2000398934016


PS C:\Users\jaro> Get-Partition -DiskNumber 2


   DiskPath: \\?\scsi#disk&ven_&prod_st2000dx001-1cm1#7&2e1550d9&0&050000#{53f56307-b6bf-11d0-94f2-00a0c91efb8b}

PartitionNumber  DriveLetter Offset                                                      Size Type
---------------  ----------- ------                                                      ---- ----
1                           1048576                                                   100 MB System
2                           105906176                                                  16 MB Reserved
3                C           122683392                                              361.28 GB Basic
4                           388041277440                                              625 MB Recovery
5                A           388697686016                                            80.05 GB Basic
6                           474649460736                                                1 GB Unknown
7                G           475724251136                                             1.39 TB Basic


PS C:\Users\jaro> Get-Partition -DiskNumber 4


   DiskPath: \\?\scsi#disk&ven_nvme&prod_force_mp600#5&eb22283&0&000000#{53f56307-b6bf-11d0-94f2-00a0c91efb8b}

PartitionNumber  DriveLetter Offset                                                      Size Type
---------------  ----------- ------                                                      ---- ----
1                           1048576                                                   100 MB System
2                           105906176                                                  16 MB Reserved
3                           122683392                                              361.28 GB Unknown
4                           388041277440                                              625 MB Recovery
5                E           388697686016                                            80.05 GB Basic
6                           474649460736                                                1 GB Unknown
7                F           475724251136                                             1.39 TB Basic
```

---

#### BCD contents

```
PS C:\Windows\system32> .\bcdedit.exe

Windows Boot Manager
--------------------
identifier              {bootmgr}
device                  partition=\Device\HarddiskVolume11
path                    \EFI\MICROSOFT\BOOT\BOOTMGFW.EFI
description             Windows Boot Manager
locale                  en-US
inherit                 {globalsettings}
default                 {current}
resumeobject            {4c5f0d94-502c-11ed-ba51-f3bde6dbb2bd}
displayorder            {current}
toolsdisplayorder       {memdiag}
timeout                 30

Windows Boot Loader
-------------------
identifier              {current}
device                  partition=C:
path                    \Windows\system32\winload.efi
description             Windows 11
locale                  en-US
inherit                 {bootloadersettings}
recoverysequence        {4c5f0d96-502c-11ed-ba51-f3bde6dbb2bd}
displaymessageoverride  Recovery
recoveryenabled         Yes
isolatedcontext         Yes
allowedinmemorysettings 0x15000075
osdevice                partition=C:
systemroot              \Windows
resumeobject            {4c5f0d94-502c-11ed-ba51-f3bde6dbb2bd}
nx                      OptIn
bootmenupolicy          Standard
```

---

Update:

I tried to make both Windows installations appear in the BCD, but that step also failed, presumably because the fs-ids are identical on those drives.

```
X:\sources>bootrec /rebuildbcd
Scanning all discs for Windows installations.

Please wait, since this may take a while...

Successfully scanned Windows installations.
Total identified Windows installations:2 
[1]  \\?\GLOBALROOT\Device\HarddiskVolume28\Windows
Add installation to bootlist? Yes(Y)/No(N)/All(A):Y
[2]  D:\Windows
Add installation to bootlist? Yes(Y)/No(N)/All(A):Y
The requested system device cannot be identified due do multiple indistinguishable devices potentially matching the identification criteria
```

I did a few more things to try and save this system like changing the filesystem system id with the tool `volumeid.exe`, but wound up with the BSOD:

```
 Error Code 0xc0000185 is caused by a corruption of files 
 related to the boot function of a Windows PC.
```

I guess it's still possible to fix the boot loader, but since information on this is hard to get. I might just give up, move on and note for the future:

DO NOT BOOT WINDOWS WITH AN IDENTICAL CLONE PRESENT ON A DIFFERENT DISK AND CONTROLLER, BECAUSE THE OS MAY MESS UP YOUR ORIGINAL INSTALLATION.

Comment: Care to provide a screenshot of the partition layout of all drives and your BCD?

Comment: Screenshots are discouraged afaik, but yes. I have provided that update. Not for all drives, but for the relevant ones.

Comment: Side note: you claim your Linux is fine, but *in general* problems may arise also in Linux when you boot with the original and the clone connected. Nowadays Linux commonly uses UUIDs to identify filesystems to mount. The same UUID reported by more than one filesystem is asking for trouble, although hopefully each of your Linuxes will still be bootable after separating the drives. [It's worse if you use Btrfs; identical UUIDs will be interpreted as one filesystem occupying multiple devices, this can be fatal](https://btrfs.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/Gotchas#Block-level_copies_of_devices).

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski I have never seen a duplicate fs-uuid *brick* the original installation and/or bootloader - even with BTRFS. But you do have a point, thanks for the reminder.

Answer (score 0):

A) you may have better luck with some dedicated cloning software
B) try and rotate the fs-ids before booting the original os next time, but may leave the clone in an unbootable state because the fs-ids are probably used in the windows boot loader
C)

### **DO NOT BOOT WINDOWS WITH AN IDENTICAL CLONE PRESENT ON A DIFFERENT DISK AND CONTROLLER, BECAUSE THE OS MAY MESS UP YOUR ORIGINAL INSTALLATION.**